# How to run a function once per second separated from the requests on Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm developing a simple API in Flask, it isn't REST or anything.

There's a module that returns real-time data in a list.

The module in question

```
# module.py
def get_data():
    do_something()
    return [info_from_somewhere, info_from_other_place]
```

And the app

```
# app.py
import module

@app.route('/')
def get_data():
    return jsonify(data=module.get_data()[0])
```

The thing is, this would run the function every time someones requests that route. And as the data is only one for all, I want to give it for every request but running the function just once.

**Edit:** I tried this:

```
got_data = module.get_data()

@app.route('/')
def get_data():
    return jsonify(data=got_data[0])
```

Works, but don't refresh the list. So my question would be "how can I refresh it every second?" I tried sleep but it freezes my app

Comment: You've already got the answer -- call the function once and just return the resulting list instead of evaluating it each time the view is hit. What's your question? Where to put it?

Comment: But wouldn't that run it just once? My question would be "how do I do this?"...

Comment: You need to edit your question to be more clear. Your last edit completely changed the context and meaning of the question from "how can I run a function just once" to "how can I run a function once per second but divorced from the context of a request/view".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could achieve this with [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). From project page.

> Celery is an asynchronous task queue/job queue based on distributed message passing. It is focused on real-time operation, but supports scheduling as well.

Other solution could be done by spawning a thread, that will update the data every second, but this could get tricky really fast.

```
from threading import Timer
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
DATA = "data"

def update_data(interval):
    Timer(interval, update_data, [interval]).start()
    global DATA
    DATA = DATA + " updating..."

# update data every second
update_data(1)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return DATA

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```